# How to fetch data from a SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

What I want to achieve: I have a SQL request getting all data, which I'm using to make graphs. But I also would like to extract more specifically today's (2022-08-31) price to print it somewhere.

So in following database table:

```
date        | price
------------+------------
2022-08-31  | 10.0
2022-08-30  | 32.0 
2022-08-29  | 20.0
2022-08-28  | 12.0
```

Where I run this SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `price_log` 
WHERE 1
```

Options:

1. Fetching the data - I suppose it's possible to fetch today's price from my request but I don't know how.
2. Making a second more specific request - I am not sure about that one, and I think (but don't know why) it's not the best way to do it (performance wise) tell me if my concern is correct.

   ```
    SELECT * 
    FROM price_log 
    WHERE DATE(date) = CURDATE()
   ```

Comment: So loop over your records then, until you find the one that has that date.

Comment: Isn't that a performance concern if my table contains a lot more data ?

Comment: _"without having to make a specific querry with the WHERE function"_ - why though? This makes really rather little sense. The database is _made_ for this kind of stuff, and with a proper index on the date column, you can even improve performance if necessary. Selecting _all_ records instead, only to loop through them afterwards with PHP to only find a single one out of those, is really a less than optimal approach.

Comment: Like.. you can't do `WHERE date  =NOW()`? Why not? Seems like a silly requirement.

Comment: I mean, if that date is the first row in his table, just do `SELECT * FROM price_log LIMIT 1`. if it's the last entry in his table, he can do `SELECT * FROM price_log ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 1`, assuming he declared a primary key, but I do agree with CBroe, why would he not use the `WHERE` query?

Comment: Well, because I'm using the request to make graphs, I would like to fetch only today's data without having to make a more specific second one. Unless you think that's a better idea. @CBroe

Comment: _"I would like to fetch only today's data without having to make a more specific second one"_ - what "second one" are you talking about? You make _one_ query, that is a specific as it needs to be to begin with. If you only need the data for one specific date - then write a query that selects only that data.

Comment: @CBroe So I should make a "SELECT * FROM price_log WHERE 1" for my graph's and a "SELECT * FROM price_log WHERE  DATE(date) = CURDATE()" for today's price ?

Comment: So you do _not_ need only today's data, but all of it (your phrasing here is really rather confusing) - then you could determine today's value in a PHP loop as well. How performant that will be, depends on what amount of records you will actually be dealing with. A second select might indeed be a better idea, if we are talking thousands of records or more.

Comment: FYI comments are not for extended discussion. This question needs a lot of clarity, and this clarity needs to be be in the question (please *edit* your question). As written, it's confusing (it's unclear precisely what you're trying to accomplish, and unclear what the issue is with running a specific query). You mentioned something about a graph as well, but that's buried in comments (and it's unclear how that connects to your original question; again, this needs clarification, and needs to be *in your question*)

Comment: @CBroe And I suppose your last comment solved my question. Because yes indeed, my table could contain many more data.

Answer (score 1):

You can get current date record with the below sql query :

`CURDATE()` is a sql function.

```
"SELECT price FROM price_log WHERE DATE(date) = CURDATE()"
```

Does it work for you?